# How can I use mutagen.py to clear mp3 metadata?

Tags: python, mp3, metadata, mutagen

I'd like to clear all metadata in an MP3 file, and I'm already using Mutagen in my project. 
Is there a way I could simply clear all the metadata from the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can use the `delete` method of the `MP3` object:

```
mp3 = MP3(fname)
mp3.delete()
mp3.save()
```

Source: [Remove ID3 tags from MP3 files](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577139-remove-id3-tags-from-mp3-files/)

Comment: Seems to work on all id3 versions.  If not try this instead: `tags = ID3(file)` `tags.delete()` `tags.save(file)`